# Calling self inside a method in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I'm trying to do an arithmetic sequence class in smalltalk, I'm having some trouble with doing a printOn method.
Here is the code I have, for some reason it would fail upon getting to the self part, I dont understand why though

```
printOn: aStream
    |i retValue|
    retValue := ''.
    i := 0.
    [i < myCount ] whileTrue: [retValue := retValue + ('', self valueOf: i). i := i -1.].
    aStream nextPutAll: retValue
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`,` is a binary message. It has a higher priority than the `valueOf:` keyword message. What you are actually executing looks like this:

```
('', self) valueOf: i
```

You need to put parenthesis to explicitly tell that you want `valueOf:` executed first:

```
'', (self valueOf: i)
```

#### secondly:

you do `retValue + "probably string"`. Are you sure that you want to do `+` in string and not `,` which is a concatenation?

#### thirdly:

you start from 0 and decrease `i` by 1 on each step. Are you sure you will not end up in an infinite loop?

#### fourthly

why do you need `whileTrue:`? can't you do something like:

```
1 to: myCount do: [ :i |
    retValue := retValue + ('', (self valueOf: i - 1)) ]
```

also please note that it's weird in Smalltalk that your first index is 0 and last is myCount - 1. Usually you start with 1 and end with the size of collection.

#### fifthly

I've just noticed that you are actually concatenating an empty string with `self valueOf: i`. That does not make any sense.

---

In case you just need to print things on the stream do something like:

```
printOn: aStream
    1 to: myCount do: [ :i |
        aStream nextPutAll: (self valueOf: i) asString) ]
```

or

```
printOn: aStream
    (1 to: myCount)
        do: [ :i | aStream nextPutAll: (self valueOf: i) asString) ]
        separatedBy: [ aStream nextPutAll: ', ' ]
```

I don't know if `valueOf:` returns a string, if it does, no need to send `asString` to the result

Comment: thanks a lot! im new to smalltalk, glad to see theres a community here on so. on secondly - how would it be done? thirdly - youre correct.fourthly - i started with a for loop and thought maybe ill succeed with a while loop. fifthly - i didnt understand that - care to explain? 
the in case - that solved it, how might i add a comma between the values of?

Comment: @Infested **2:** you can use `+` with numerical collections: `#(2 3 5) + 2 = #(4 5 7)`. If you have `'foo'` and `'bar`' and want to get `'foobar'` you need to use `,` message. **5:** `'ab', 'cd' = 'a', 'bcd' = '', 'abcd' = 'abcd'`. You are concatenation empty string with something. No matter how many empty strings you will have at the beginning, the result will be anyway the non empty string that you have. I've added another example

Answer (score 6):

Smalltalk has a rigorous precedence order for evaluating messages.

Expressions within parentheses ( ) are evaluated first.
Then Unary messages (messages consisting of an object followed by a message)
Then Binary messages (messages consisting of an object followed by non-alphabetic character followed by another object)
Then Keyword messages - i.e. keyword messages are evaluated last. (Keywords are alphabetic strings ending in a colon, and a keyword message can contain several keywords).
Where precedence is equal, expressions are evaluated from left to right.

In the expression you wrote, the first element evaluated in

```
  retValue + ( '', self valueOf: i)
```

is

```
 ( '', self valueOf: i)
```

The first element evaluated within that expression is

```
 '', self
```

The result of that then becomes the receiver of the

```
 valueOf: 1
```

keyword message.

Incidentally, I would write

i := i - 1

To ensure that anySmalltalk would correctly interpret it as a binary expression, as opposed to i followed by an integer object, -1

Comment: Is there really any Smalltalk dialect that parses `i -1` as "variable `i` and number `-1`? Genuine question